# Slim Framework 2 - Not getting HTTP 304 code with etag()

Tags: php, http, http-headers, slim, slim-2

I am using slim framework 2 `etag()` to fetch cache data, all working fine i am getting the cache data with the postman or any rest client but i am getting `HTTP 200 OK` response all time in the rest client but as it should be `HTTP 304` when the data comes from cache

> below is my slim api:

```
 $app->get('/getNew', function () use ($app){
     $app->etag('uniqueEtag12');
    echo "I am updated one";
  });
```

I don't have any idea why every time i am getting `200 OK` response code in the rest client as i am getting the cache data in the response, below is my rest client response snap

[image]

why this status code always `200 OK` why i am not getting status code `304` please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `etag()` method does two things:

1. Add the `ETag` header to the response
2. Send a 304 status response if the client sends an `If-None-Match` header with the value `uniqueEtag12`

Therefore, I think that your request does not include an `If-None-Match` header.

Example code:

index.php:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app) {
    $app->etag('1234');
    echo "Hello world on " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
});


$app->run();
```

Test using curl.

No `If-None-Match` header:
$ curl -i http://localhost:8888/hello

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.15
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Etag: "1234"

Hello world on 2017-05-04 07:12:40
```

With an `If-None-Match` header:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8888/hello -H 'If-None-Match: "1234"'
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.15
Etag: "1234"
```

Comment: but i am getting cache values

Comment: Is there a `If-None-Match` header in the HTTP request?

Comment: That's why there's no 304. the [code](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/Slim/Slim.php#L818-L823) in `etag()` looks for that header.

Comment: @ Rob Allen would you please give me an example of code in your answer